# Rendering Error when executing Yarn Run with Boilerplate and Electron-React

Tags: html, node.js, electron, boilerplate

I am very new to this and will probably have a hard time explaining the problem well. I am using boilerplate and electron react to open a webpage. Up until today it was working fine, however all of a sudden my console reads an error when using

```
yarn run
```

The error is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   renderer.dev.js:1
```

The window appears but nothing renders.

I've tried to revert my commits but the problem doesn't go away, I'm unsure of what route to pursue with the problem.

Any guidance would be appreciated

**EDIT**

It looks like sajad saderi's suggestion of removing node_modules and reinstalling it removed the specific error message, and my renderer.dev.js file has loaded. However, now the following appears

```
Uncaught Error: None of the binaries loaded successfully. Is your node version >= 10.15 ?
    at failIfNoBinaryExported (renderer.dev.js:192034)
    at Object.liveLoad (renderer.dev.js:192030)
    at Object../node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/bootstrap.js (renderer.dev.js:192050)
    at __webpack_require__ (renderer.dev.js:771)
    at fn (renderer.dev.js:131)
    at renderer.dev.js:192072
    at Object../node_modules/msnodesqlv8/lib/connection.js (renderer.dev.js:192508)
    at __webpack_require__ (renderer.dev.js:771)
    at fn (renderer.dev.js:131)
    at Object.<anonymous> (renderer.dev.js:194552)
```

The program is meant to gather data from an SQL Server using Electron React, Boilerplate, and msnodesqlv8

Comment: Can you add your project structure and renderer.dev.js?

Comment: Remove the "node_modules" folder in the project then install it again by command "yarn" or "npm install".